# Can Docker Desktop for Windows Point To Remote Docker Engine?

Tags: visual-studio, docker, windows-10, docker-desktop

I am unable to run linux containers as I run Docker in my development vm which has visual studio installed and I have not been ablt to get it working yet as it is an unsupported scenario and many of the google solutions have unfortunately not resolved it for me.

However, I was thinking that maybe I could keep Docker Desktop running on my dev vm (so that VS would be happy it was still "local") but actually have the Docker engine/daemon bit running on a remote host where linux containers actually work - is it possible to repoint Docker Desktop for Windows to a Docker engine on a remote host?

Apologies if my terminology is rubbish, I am new to Docker. Also, I have done some searching and have seen articles and messages talking about docker machine and DOCKER_HOST environment variables, but I cannot see anything yet that applies to Docker Desktop (e.g. I don't have that env variable set on my docker windows vm so maybe it doesn't use that mechanism).

Thanks in advance